# How to customize file path for 404 redirection in php?

Tags: 404-error, wp-redirect, template-redirect

I made a plugin with a custom post type `postcard`.
Most of `postcards` are private.

I would like to redirect the logged out user in a specific php file inside my plugin instead of the `404.php` or `achive.php`.

I tried with `template_redirect` action like this :

```
add_action( "template_redirect", array( "MyClass", "is_redirection" ) );

Class MyClass{

    public static function is_redirection(){
        if( is_404() ) {
            global $post_type;
            if( $post_type === "postcard" ){
                $templates_dir = get_current_plugin_templates_dir_path();
                $page404 = $templates_dir . "/404-" . $post_type . ".php";
                if ( file_exists( $page404 ) ) {
                   wp_redirect( $page404 );
                   exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

My probleme here is `$page404` is a file path, not an url so...
How can I do this wihtout using `.htaccess`?

Comment: I'm not sure what `get_current_plugin_templates_dir_path()` is -- I don't think it's a WordPress function.

Comment: `get_current_plugin_templates_dir_path()` is just a function I did to get a path like  `file-path-to-my-plugin-dir/front-end/templates/`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, using [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/):

```
...
// Assumes that your templates are in a subdirectory called 'templates' in your plugin. 
// Adjust accordingly.
$templates_dir = plugins_url( 'templates', __FILE__ );
$page_404      = $templates_dir . '/404-' . $post_type . '.php' );
...
```

**Update: `template_include`**

If you want to have WordPress loaded up, you might be better off to use the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', array( 'MyClass', '404_template' );
class MyClass {
    function 404_template( $template ) {
        if ( is_404() ) {
            global $post_type;
            $my_template = plugins_url( 'templates/404-' . $post_type . '.php' , __FILE__ );
            if ( file_exists( $my_template ) ) {
                $template = $my_template;
            }
        }
        return $template;
    }
}
```

Comment: The redirection woks in your case but, without loading the wordpress core.
For example : `defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;` inside `404-postcard.php` executes `exit`. Maybe there is a way to overwrite the 404 file path before running `$wp_query->set_404();`

Comment: Instead of using the `template_redirect` action hook, you might be better suited by using the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter. See my update.

Comment: `is_404()` return false at this moment :/, `template_include` seems to be earlier.